# NSMethodSignature in Swift

Tags: objective-c, swift

In ObjC I have:

```
NSMethodSignature *ms = [[object.target class] instanceMethodSignatureForSelector:object.selector];
NSInvocation *invocation = [NSInvocation invocationWithMethodSignature:ms];
```

In Swift I get error:

```
'NSObject' does not have a member named 'instanceMethodSignatureForSelector'
```

When I try this:

```
var ms:NSMethodSignature? = (object.target.dynamicType as NSObject).instanceMethodSignatureForSelector(object.success)
```

Comment: No invocations in swift. Rethink your approach or keep using Objective C.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Getting a method signature is rather easy:

```
var target = NSObject()
var selector = Selector("success")

var signature: NSMethodSignature? = target.methodSignatureForSelector(selector)
```

However, using `NSInvocation` is forbidden:

[image: NSInvocation not available]

Rethink your approach.

Answer (score 5):

There are no invocations in Swift. But perhaps you never needed an invocation here:

```
NSMethodSignature *ms = 
    [[object.target class] instanceMethodSignatureForSelector:object.selector];
```

So at some time you formed or had access to an object (`object`) with a `target` and a `selector`. This suggests that at that time you could have formed a closure in which you call that method on that target. For example:

```
let clos = {() -> () in object.someMethod(); return; }
```

Now you have a value `clos` of type `() -> ()` that you can store, pass around, and so forth. When the time comes, you just call it:

```
clos()
```

Or, depending on the circumstances, you can store a reference to that method directly:

```
let funcref = object.someMethod
```

Again, you can later call it:

```
funcref()
```

Now that we have closures and functions as first-class linguistic citizens, the dynamism of Objective-C will turn out to have been, in many cases, just a crutch that is no longer needed.

And if you find that you really, really did need it, Objective-C has not gone away and you can mix it into your project.

Answer (score 1):

An addon to **@matt**'s answer...

If you have multiple functions with the same name and different parameters, you should ensure that the function reference is pointing to the intended function.

```
let funcref: () -> () = object.funcName
```

If you do NOT do this, unexpected things happen (if you don't just get an error). Let's take a look!

---

#### Scenario 1:

```
func doStuff (withThis: Any) {}

func doStuff (withThis: Any, andThis: Any, alsoThis: Any) {}

let funcref = doStuff
```

In this case, **no error is given** and `funcref` is equal to the function with **the most parameters**.

This only occurs when:

• One function takes **exactly 1 parameter**

• The other function takes **more than 1 parameter**

---

#### Scenario 2:

```
func doStuff (withThis: Any) {}

func doStuff () {}

let funcref = doStuff
```

In this case, **no error is given** and `funcref` is equal to the function with **NO parameters**.

This only occurs when:

• One function takes **NO parameters**

• The other function takes **exactly 1 parameter**

---

#### Scenario 3:

```
func doStuff () {}

func doStuff (withThis: Any) {}

func doStuff (withThis: Any, andThis: Any) {}

func doStuff (withThis: Any, andThis: Any, alsoThis: Any) {}

let funcref = doStuff
```

In this case, `funcref`'s line will give the error:

`Could not find an overload for 'doStuff' that accepts the supplied arguments`

This only occurs when:

• There are **more than 3 functions that take 1 or more parameters** and have the same name

---

#### Scenario 4:

```
func doStuff () {}

func doStuff (withThis: Any, andThis: Any) {}

let funcref = doStuff
```

In this case, `funcref`'s line will give the error:

`Ambiguous use of 'doStuff'`.

This only occurs when:

• All the above scenarios are not relevant