# Default Parameters

Tags: swift, default-parameters

I have a function with one parameter. This parameter has a default value. (true)

```
func disableButton(animated: Bool = true) {

    if (animated) {
        ...         
    } else {
        ...
    }
}
```

So i can call the function as:

```
disableButton(animated: true)
```

or:

```
disableButton()
```

and they give me the same result.

Now I have an NSTimer running a selector on completion like this:

```
buttonFadeTimer = NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(NSTimeInterval(1.5), target: self, selector: Selector("disableButton"), userInfo: nil, repeats: false)
```

It will send the disableButton() message on completion. However on completion it causes the app to crash.

If i do:

```
func disableButton() {
    disableButton(animated: true)
}
```

Then the timer successfully sends that message and the app does not crash.

Of course this is really ugly and kind of limits the great Swift feature of default parameters.

Is this a bug (that I should report) or am I doing it wrong?

Thanks for any help!

Comment: Does it crash with `Selector("disableButton:")`?

Comment: Yes, this makes it crash.

Comment: I guess the selector alone won't work then. Perhaps you can try to adopt this approach https://github.com/jivadevoe/NSTimer-Blocks

Answer (score 1):

There's a difference between `-disableButton` and `-disableButton:` selectors. But you can't just use your desired selector like this:

```
buttonFadeTimer = NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(NSTimeInterval(1.5), target: self, selector: Selector("disableButton:"), userInfo: nil, repeats: false)
```

because `NSTimer` here assumes selector with no arguments or selector with single argument (which will be used to pass firing NSTimer instance).

I believe, you should migrate from using selectors, as you want to use all that great features Swift delivers, as far as selectors is outdated pattern.

Just a note: it *could* work if you use `"disableButton:"` selector, maybe NSTimer's pointer will be interpreted as true and maybe not, not sure what will happen (maybe it could crash due to Swift strong typing stuff). But depending on that behaviour is a bad practice which could lead to bugs which are extremely hard to exterminate.

Comment: Thanks for your help. `"disableButton:"` makes it crash.

How do I do this without using selectors? Both methods in the documentation examples use selectors.

Comment: @Andy That's an interesting question, quick search gives nothing special, just some pieces of knowledge: http://www.samuelmullen.com/2014/07/using-swifts-closures-with-nstimer and  http://stackoverflow.com/a/24159796/1032151
I thought there could be a built in feature of using closures or direct function referencing, but didn't manage to find any evidence of that. Maybe there'll be (or is) something which goes in place of NSTrimer, but for now it looks like selectors is the only way to go. (Correct me if I'm wrong about the last point)